# How to return the last upper bound docplex?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, docplex

I try to solve a model in docplex(python) the model was stopped after a specific time limit. I want when the model stop return the best upper bound was found.

Comment: Are you minimizing or maximizing? Do you want the bound of the last node processed or the best bound found by the solver?

Comment: minimizing. I want the best bound found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you solve a docplex model, it creates an internal `SolveDetails` object that contains the best bound you're looking for. You can access it in two ways:

1. Assuming you've defined your docplex model as `model` (an instance of the class `docplex.mp.model.Model`)

```
print(model.get_solve_details().best_bound)
```

2. Assuming you've stored your model's solution in `sol` (an instance of the class `docplex.mp.solution.SolveSolution`)

```
sol = model.solve()
print(sol.solve_details.best_bound)
```

Check out the [documentation](http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.sdetails.html#docplex.mp.sdetails.SolveDetails.best_bound) for more details.